# How $y^2 \over (1+y^2)$ can be simplified to $1 - \frac 1{(1 + y^2)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Basically, I am trying to solve a differential equation, and in my book there is this statement
"We can simplify $\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}$ to $1- 
\frac{1}{1+y^2}$"
I want to know what are the underline steps that were taken to get this $1 - \frac{1}{1 + y^2}$.
Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{y^2}{1+y^2} = \frac{(1+y^2) - 1}{(1+y^2)}$ should be helpful, along with the fact that $\frac{a+c}{b} = \frac ab + \frac cb$. [This is the page you should visit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) if you wish to write your expressions more neatly and presentably.

Comment: this is a common ‘trick’ of adding zero. the authors added $0=1+(-1)$ in the numerator of the fraction and then simplified.  another common trick you may see is to multiply by one in the form of $1=a/a$ for some non-zero $a$, whatever it may be.

Comment: Thanks, guys this was helpful.

Comment: @nomantufail Ok, welcome!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Can you post an answer or even the OP, can you? This makes sure the question *is answered*. Or I can, as you wish?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I think you can do so. I would have, but I don't know, I just feel it's too small! Please do so. I for one will take a look once you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just posting what @TeresaLisbon said in the comment (of course with slight modifications in presentation and speech).

So, we have
$$\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}=\frac{y^2+{\color{blue} 1}-{\color{blue} 1}}{y^2+1}$$
Then, we can use the fact that subtraction is distributive over division, so we can "distribute" over. The expression becomes
$$\frac{y^2+1}{y^2+1}-\frac{1}{y^2+1}$$
The left term nicely cancels out and we get
$$\boxed{1-\frac{1}{y^2+1}}$$

Hope this helps. Have a good day :)